# How to exclude cells with specific values from a partial match search criterion?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**My Question**

I will leave a much more detailed explanation below, but here is my problem in short.  I need to know how to check a string for a specific character, in my case "/".  If the cell has a "/", I then want to split it into two separate strings, one containing everything before the slash, and one containing everything afterwards.  Then, as long neither string equals either of two different values, do something.  I would appreciate any help!

---

**Detailed Explanation of Problem**

I have a spreadsheet I use to schedule many different classes at different times of the day, and in different locations.  The first sheet has the time in 15 minute increments running along the left side of my sheet.  The header row has every location in my facility.  I then manually write the name of a class in the time/location grid.  Also, when a class size is sufficiently large, we will oftentimes split it into two or three groups and assign every group to a different location.  In order to account for this, I will write "B" and "C" versions of the class.  For example: if "Level 1" is a class name, and I need to split it into 3 separate groups at 8:30, I would enter "Level 1", "Level 1 B", and "Level 1 C" under different locations, all in the 8:30 row.  See the image below.
[image]

After planning my classes according to time and location, I have a second sheet that will organize all of the information so that the time runs along the left side of the second sheet, the class names (followed by the "B" and "C" variants) are in the header row, and the locations then fall under the class name.  Every cell in the second sheet contains a formula that carries out this process.  By default, if a "B" or "C" variant does not find a match, it will retrieve the value from the original class name.  This is what the information from the first image looks like in my second sheet.
[image]

After using the spreadsheet for a few months, I've encountered the problem where every now and then, I need to schedule 2 classes at the same time and in the same location.  If I try to write both class names into a cell (i.e. "Level 1/Level 3"), the formulas on the second sheet can no longer find the class names on the first sheet since the formulas are matching a cell's entire value.  I know I can use wildcards, such as "*" before and after the class name in order to partial match the cell, and the formulas will then work, but I have another difficulty.  If I use a * wildcard in a formula searching for any class name that is not followed by a B or C, the formula can also pull data from any cell that contains a B or C variant.  For example: if I am searching for any cell that partially contains "Level 3", the formula could be satisfied with cells that contain "Level 1/Level 3", "level 3 C", or "Level 3 B/Level 2 C".  I only want to retrieve information from the cells that partially match the exact value "Level 3".  This is what it looks like currently.
[image]

And this is what I want it to look like.
[image]

As I stated before, I have been using formulas to organize the data the way I want.  I believe my problem can be solved much more simply with apps script.  I know how to use createTextFinder() to find all the cells that contain a partial match with my class names.  I do not however know how to limit the search to cells that do not contain the B and C variants of the class.  My current idea would be to use textFinder to find all cells that contain a partial or complete match.  I could then check to see if the cell contains a "/"; if it does, I could somehow split the string into two separate strings - 1 for everything before the slash, and one for everything after.  Then, as long as neither string equals the "B" or "C" variant of the class, get the location name and write under the class name at the correct time.  I know how to do just about everything in my idea, except for splitting the string and comparing both halves to the class name.  Again, I would appreciate any help anyone can give me!

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following and see if any meets your needs as starting points to "...do something"

**Split in 2 columns**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"Level 3$|Level 3/"),SPLIT(A2:A,"/"),""))
```

**1 column**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A11,"Level 3$|Level 3/"),"/","")))
```

**1 column + the rest**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A11,"Level 3$|Level 3/"),"/",""),A2:A11))
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs.

If in further need, please share a test sheet so as you can be easier helped.)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for the delayed response.  I am currently working your solution into my spreadsheet with my other formulas.  I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Is there a way to return just the column number of the match found in the 1 column formula you proposed?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. The first formula splits up into 2 columns. Don't you need the 2nd one? I think what you ask for is something completely different from *"...I only want to retrieve information from the cells that partially match the exact value "Level 3""*. If still in need please share a test sheet and maybe post a new question. In any case, Please remember that when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.